# Executing build with parameters from Java program

Tags: jenkins, cloudbees

I am trying to execute a Jenkins build from my Java program using the Resty framework (using Resty isn't a requirement, just seemed like the easiest way). It works fine for jobs without parameters, including authentication, however I am trying to execute a build with a parameter but I am getting the (non-descript) Error 500 returned from Jenkins server.

```
URI jenkinsURI = new URI("https://"+jenkinsServer+"/job/bowling%20Q%20build/build?token="+jenkinsToken);
String b = URLEncoder.encode("json={\"parameter\": [{\"name\": \"git_tag\", \"value\": \"v1\"}],\"\":\"\"", "UTF-8");
System.out.println("My Results: "+r.text(jenkinsURI, Resty.content(b)));
```

Any idea how to do this? I have followed [these instructions](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API) for sending the JSON and it works fine from curl, but does not from Java Resty.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I didn't/can't use the URLEncoder. Once I changed the Resty.content to

```
System.out.println("My Results: "+r.text(jenkinsURI, Resty.form(Resty.data("json", "{\"parameter\": [{\"name\": \"git_tag\", \"value\": \"1.0.4\"}],\"\":\"\"}"))));
```

it started working fine.